# How to make an object move relative to the mouse pointer using actionscript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3

I am making a game where I want my character to move towards the mouse pointer when pressing forward and for it to strafe left and right with the respecting arrow keys.

Here is my current code:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
//Event Listners
stage.addChild(crosshair_mc);
crosshair_mc.mouseEnabled = false;
crosshair_mc.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fl_CustomMouseCursor);

function fl_CustomMouseCursor(event:Event)
{
    crosshair_mc.x = stage.mouseX;
    crosshair_mc.y = stage.mouseY;
}
Mouse.hide();

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE,facecursor);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, fl_KeyboardDownHandler);
//Functions
function facecursor(event):void
{
    character_mc.rotation = (180 * Math.atan2(mouseY - character_mc.y,mouseX - character_mc.x))/Math.PI + 90;

}


function fl_KeyboardDownHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    trace("Key Code Pressed: " + event.keyCode);
    if (event.keyCode == 38)
    {
        character_mc.y = character_mc.y - 5;
    }
    if (event.keyCode == 40)
    {
        character_mc.y = character_mc.y + 5;
    }
        if (event.keyCode == 39)
    {
        character_mc.x = character_mc.x + 5;
    }
        if (event.keyCode == 37)
    {
        character_mc.x = character_mc.x - 5;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the rotation part right, now all you need is to incorporate that with `cos` and `sin` for the `x` and `y` axis respectively. Example:

```
var speed:Number = 8;
var angle:Number = Math.atan2(mouseY - character_mc.y, mouseX - character_mc.x);

character_mc.rotation = angle * 180 / Math.PI;
character_mc.x += Math.cos( angle ) * speed;
character_mc.y += Math.sin( angle ) * speed;
```

To avoid confusion, I would stop adding `90` degrees onto the rotation and instead rotate your graphics to face right / east.

The strafing thing uses the same logic, you just want to add a quarter of a circle to the rotation in whichever direction you want to strafe. FYI, a quater of a circle in radians is PI / 2. There are 2 PI radians in one circle:

```
// Augment angle for strafing.
angle += Math.PI / 2;
```

Comment: @user2130844 However you would like it to be implemented with your code...

Comment: yes but how will i implement it to make it do what i wanted it to bacause i just replaced the old code with that before and it made the character_mc follow the cursor

Comment: @user2130844 Yep so just do the updates to x and y when you're pressing the appropriate keys like you had original code.

Comment: Can you please show how that code will fit into my code to get the desired effect?